# Trying to find sign-in link in microsoft.com using scrapy spider

Tags: html, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to find sign in link via scrapy crawler on any website, for example www.microsoft.com. However when I get initial response from the website the sign in link isn't present. But when I visit the website I am able to see the sign in link in the "View Source".

The code is written to get all the links by checking for `<a>` tag in response using `xpath`. There are other links that are present in response, however the sign in link is not visible.

```
    for links in response.xpath("//a"): ---> to get the links 
        if links.xpath("@href").extract() and links.xpath("@href").extract()[0]: 
                link = links.xpath("@href").extract()[0]

                if(link.startswith("http")):
                    searched_url = link
                else :
                    if(link.startswith("/")):
                        link = link[1:len(link)]

                    searched_url = response.url + link

                all_other_urls.append(searched_url)
                print(searched_url) ---> printing the links present in the response.
```

The response I receive has link present in this manner (refer `signInUrl`). :

```
            <div id="meControl" class="c-me"  data-signinsettings='{"containerId":"meControl","enabled":true,"headerHeight":48,"debug":false,"extensibleLinks":[],"userData":{"idp":"msa","firstName":"","lastName":"","memberName":"","cid":"","authenticatedState":"3"},"rpData":{"preferredIdp":"msa","msaInfo":{"signInUrl":"https://www.microsoft.com/mscomhp/onerf/signin?EEL=True\u0026pcexp=True","signOutUrl":"https://www.microsoft.com/mscomhp/onerf/signout?pcexp=True","meUrl":"https://login.live.com/me.srf?wa=wsignin1.0"},"aadInfo":{"signOutUrl":"https://www.microsoft.com/mscomhp/onerf/signout?pcexp=True","appId":"","siteUrl":"","blockMsaFed":true}}}' data-m='{"cN":"GlobalNav_Account_cont","cT":"Container","id":"c6c1c7c2m1r1a1","sN":6,"aN":"c1c7c2m1r1a1"}'>
                    <div class="msame_Header">
                            <div class="msame_Header_name st_msame_placeholder">Sign in</div>
                    </div>
```

My code will work if the link is present in `<a>` tag which I can see on website view source:

```
 a class="mectrl_resetStyle mectrl_trigger" id="mectrl_main_trigger" aria-label="Sign in to your account" href="https://www.microsoft.com/mscomhp/onerf/signin?EEL=True&amp;pcexp=True&amp;ru=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2F" target="_top"><div class="mectrl_header" aria-hidden="true"><div class="mectrl_headertext mectrl_truncate">  Sign in  /div> div class="mectrl_profilepic mectrl_glyph glyph_signIn_circle" id="mectrl_headerPicture" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></div></div></a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the signin-url without rendering the page as follows:

```
import json

signin_settings = response.xpath('//*[@id="meControl"]/@data-signinsettings').extract_first()
signin_d = json.loads(signin_settings)
signin_url = signin_d['rpData']['msaInfo']['signInUrl']
```

Comment: I would like to write a generic code which can crawl multiple websites and find the sign-in URL. The code suggestion given by you will only work for Microsoft.com. Sorry for the confusion as my initial question asks only about Microsoft.com. I have edited by question.